# Text instead of integer in Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I just received an Excel file from a colleague and I'm baffled by one of the formulas.

It's a Vlookup function where the column index number is equal to DTCN.

I tried looking up this formula but can't find it anywhere. Here it is:

> =VLOOKUP($A15;KPI!$A$4:$AN$133;DTCN;FALSE)

What really matters:

> =VLOOKUP(lookup value; table array; DTCN; range lookup)

I work in Excel 2010 and the formula works.

My question: What does DTCN do? How does it work? Can you only use in certain circumstances? ...

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look in the Name Manager, in the Formula tab, you may find it there!

Comment: That solved it. In the name manager I found that DTCN refers to a cell in a different sheet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in :

- Formula tab
- Name Manager

you'll most probably find it there!